# GKE Usage Metering: "kube:system-overhead" namespace

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-kubernetes-engine

We currently have [GKE Usage Metering](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-usage-metering) on our Kubernetes clusters. When we ran queries on our billing dataset and the GKE resource usage with BigQuery, we found an expensive line item in our billing datasets with `kube:system-overhead` as namespace. Unable to find any [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-usage-metering) on this.

While there is a [blog post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/gke-usage-metering-507a0edb5e8e) suggesting to ignore this namespace, it doesn't mention the reason. Also, the line item for us is expensive to be ignored.

[image]

Would like to know what's overhead and its relation to cost in Kubernetes. Can someone who has worked with Kubernetes cost management shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

The [kube:system-overhead] is a dummy namespace that captures resources reserved for Kubernetes’ non-containerized node components, and the amount of resources is the difference between node capacity and node allocatable. These resources are used by non-containerized processes such as kubelet and docker daemon. Resources used by system pods such as kube-dns are attributed to the kube-system namespace. That means these are resources used by [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#memory_cpu